# How would I parse this html in php?

Tags: php, html, parsing, firefox

I've exported my Firefox bookmarks as html so I can download my extensive music collection onto my phone, my problem is there is no easy way that I know of.

My intentions is to use PHP to parse the html into an array of the URLs

Heres what the html looks like

```
<DT><A HREF="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue8PpA557Bc" ADD_DATE="1477165404" LAST_MODIFIED="1477165404" ICON_URI="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon_144-vflWmzoXw.png" ICON="data:image/png;base64,">Don Diablo - Knight Time (Official Music Video) - YouTube</A>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Whoops sorry I was trying to use a block quote.

Comment: In that case I think either of the answers below would work for you. You also can see other options on the below thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put in `$html` a correct html string, you could do it parsing the string with DOMDocument and selecting the href attributes with XPath.

```
<?php

$html = '<DT><A HREF="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue8PpA557Bc" ADD_DATE="1477165404" LAST_MODIFIED="1477165404" ICON_URI="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/favicon_144-vflWmzoXw.png" ICON="data:image/png;base64,">Don Diablo - Knight Time (Official Music Video) - YouTube</A>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

$nodeList = $xpath->query("//a/@href");

$links_array = [];

foreach($nodeList as $node){
  $links_array[] = $node->nodeValue;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($links_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

The output here is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue8PpA557Bc
)
```

Comment: Will this work with the <DT> tags or would I need to remove them?

Comment: @Adam Welcome! I'm glad this helped!

Answer (score 2):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($bookmarks);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("a") as $node) { 
    $urls[] = $node->getAttribute("href");
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the asker's problem, it would be preferable to explain how it works.